# php header loads and opens redirected page inside login form when using ajax

Tags: php, ajax

Thank you, the code might be not so good but still, this is my php:

Also I used session destroy as the could wouldnt work properly, it just signed in even if the username, password were wrong leaving  their related error though:

```
<?php
    if($_POST){
        $_SESSION['name'] = $_POST['name'];
        $_SESSION['password'] = md5($_POST['password']);
        if( $_SESSION['name'] && $_SESSION['password']){
            mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die("problem with        connection...");
            mysql_select_db("testdb");
            $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM registered WHERE name='".$_SESSION['name']."'");
            $numrows = mysql_num_rows($query);
                if($numrows != 0){
                    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){
                        $dbname = $row['name'];
                        $dbpassword = ($row['password']);
                    }
                    if($_SESSION['name']==$dbname){
                        if($_SESSION['password']==$dbpassword){
                            header("location:loggedinuser.php");
                            die();
                        }else {
                            echo "password is not correct";
                            session_destroy();
                        }
                    }else{
                        echo "name is not correct";
                        session_destroy();
                    }
                }else{
                    echo"This name is not registered";
                    session_destroy();
                }
        }else{
            echo"You have to complete the form";
            session_destroy();
        }
    }else{
        echo"Access Denied!";
        exit;
    }?>
```

And this is my ajax in another page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function testing(){
            var xmlhttp;
            if(window.XMLHttpRequest){
                xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            }else{
                xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }
            var uname = document.getElementById('name').value;
            var upassword = document.getElementById('password').value;
            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
                if(xmlhttp.readyState==4){
                    document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
                }
            }
            url = "login.php?name="+uname+"&password="+upassword;
            xmlhttp.open("POST",url,true);
            xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            xmlhttp.send("name="+uname+"&password="+upassword);
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: Post your code, we will help you if you post your code

Comment: ajax can communicate with your login.php... echo your json encoded response from login.php and the ajax will read it and do the needful. It'll be great if you could post your ajax code at least.

Comment: Clayton & JTheDev, Please see my code above:

Answer (score -1):

Maybe your login form is inside of (i)frame (or fancybox). Then, any response headers will modify this iframe. If this is your situation, you cannot make this redirect directly from PHP (when user submits this form), but you have to propagate this event in ajax code and make reload/refresh or whatever you want in javascript.

Comment: Dominik, no I dont use any iframes but my form is a modal, any suggestions?

Comment: It is most likely same situation as i described. Modals are usually created via iframes - just right click on this login form in chrome and click inspect element; then look if there is iframe in hierarchy above your form.

Comment: Dominik, I didnt find anything as iframe there, good idea though as the result of the login seems like an iframe.  Is there any other way to redirect?

Comment: Try to do this on JS side. Try to change window.locaiton in JS part of your app (so you will make redirect from client).